# Django rest framework не подтягивает username

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Я сохраняю `owner` к модели Project следующим образом

```
def add_project(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProjectPost(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save(commit=False)
            project.owner = request.user.pk
            project.owner_name = request.user.username
            project.save()
            return redirect('proj-detail', pk=project.pk)
```

В serializer'e пытаюсь получить ссылку на имя пользователя так:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
```

Но ничего не происходит

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) есть примеры.

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'desc', 'img', 'owner_name']


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projects = ProjectSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['pk', 'username', 'projects']
```